# Why does this error occur?

Tags: iphone

i am parsing the data from web service.After parsing the few records it gives this error.Somebody please the tell me what the reason behind this error?

```
[NSXMLParser length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e6d340



*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSXMLParser length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e6d340'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x026c4919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x028125de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x026c642b -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02636116 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02635cd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Foundation                          0x001053e9 -[NSXMLParser parse] + 104
    6   SexOffenders                        0x00009c30 -[UserProfileVC connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 565
    7   Foundation                          0x0006e666 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 108
    8   Foundation                          0x0006e5bf _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 133
    9   CFNetwork                           0x02c569f1 _ZN19URLConnectionClient23_clientDidFinishLoadingEPNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 285
    10  CFNetwork                           0x02d1fc72 _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 402
    11  CFNetwork                           0x02d200ea _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 1546
    12  CFNetwork                           0x02d200ea _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 1546
    13  CFNetwork                           0x02c4bdfe _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 100
    14  CFNetwork                           0x02c4bc95 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 247
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x026a5d7f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x026041dd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 333
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x026037c6 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x02603280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x026031a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x02f292c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x02f2938d GSEventRun + 115
    22  UIKit                               0x002dab58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    23  SexOffenders                        0x00002198 main + 102
    24  SexOffenders                        0x00002129 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: Post the code from your parser delegate methods and the code that creates the parser - you've not retained something somewhere and it's being released but without some code we can't help much more than that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'-[NSXMLParser length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e6d340

this shows you are calling a function which is not a member function of NSXMLParser class.

actually in your code you are calling any method which can not be invoke on the obeject of NSXMLParser class.

chechk by debugging pointer.

Comment: You need to debug by using pointers and see where the app crashed at that line see what is exactly happen.when put your mouse pointer on the object on which you will see the type of the object.

Comment: program crash on [xmlParser parse] i don't have any idea that why it happen again and again..

Comment: I think you are not allocating xmlPareser or any other object is take the location of xmlPareser.see when your pointer come on the line on which your app crases,then check the type of xmlParser is NSXMLParser or any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

I just suffered from this same issue. For me the problem was caused by this line of code:

```
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
```

This serialised the `responseObject` I was passing into the parser to XML but the parser expects an `NSData` object. Simply getting rid of that line solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar problem.

Fixed by changing my line

```
self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```

to

```
self.xmlParser = (NSXMLParser *)responseObject;
```

I found my solution from this blog

[Raywanderlick Blog](https://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial)

### Explanation for Error

This configuration of [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer] already return an initialized object and I was initializing it again using already initialized parser by considering it data object.

---

Commenting following line didn't work for me as suggested by @Hodson answer above and it doesn't make sense as this is default configuration of AFTNetworking library.

```
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
```